# Using MongoDB for a calendar web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, nosql

I have been doing web programming for few years. All this time, I have been using RDBMS. As a side project, I would like to create a web application and would like to use NoSQL. I have never used NoSQL. So I would like to use a NoSQL solution. Web app is going to be a calendar and article list that are going to be shared among a project group. I would be using Ruby on Rails.So would it be fine to use MongoDB for this web app? or do you have any other recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB should be fine. I can't think of a particularly compelling reason as to why it'd be superior to an RDBMS or one of the other key-value stores out there for this particular problem, but I can't think of a reason not to use it, either. For a learning project, it should be more than fine.

As far as interfaces go, I'm currently using MongoMapper and am happy with it, and Mongoid is picking up a lot of steam. You can even just use the Mongo driver directly - it's very usable.

Answer (score 0):

[Candy](http://github.com/SFEley/candy) looks quite nice as ruby lib. There are other like MongoMapper and Datamapper + do_mongo and likely more.